# Misplaced "Tools" link on the Review page

Tags: bug, design

The "Tools" link on the "Review" page has been misplaced for some days or even weeks now. It was on the left side before and looked just like the "Review" link, and now it is on the far right side and styled like a form button, although there is no form to submit:

[image]

At first I thought someone might have had a good reason for that, and if I stay patient I might discover that reason. But no, it's still just confusing and mildly annoying.

On the "Tools" page, the link is still styled as a link and positioned at the right place:

[image]

So there isn't even any consistency.

Please revert this change.